# Elasticsearch, understanding completion suggester

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I got the completion suggest working for `autocomplete`

However I have a question that I can't answer myself

Why are we storing the suggest in a field of the document?

```
GET /my_index/_search

{
  hits: [{
    "_id": 1,
    "suggest": {
      "input": [
        "p1",
        "p22",
      ],
      "weight": 1
    }
  }, {
    "_id": 2,
    "suggest": {
      "input": [
        "p22",
        "p3",
      ],
      "weight": 1
    }
  }]
}
```

For `autocomplete`, don't we just need a list of phrases?

```
[
  "p1",
  "p22",
  "p3"
]
```

1. What do we gain by the association of `suggest` and the `doc`?
2. as in example, multiple docs can have same `suggest` input , `p22` in the example. When I ask for `autocomplete` for `p2` I get two `p22`.
   is there a way of handling this?

Comment: Where would you store the suggestions if not in the documents themselves?

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no other way to store suggestions than storing them in a `completion` field inside the document itself. This gives you maximum flexibility, because even if two documents have the same or similar suggestions, you can give one a higher weight than the other if you deem necessary.
2. If you have multiple documents with the same suggestions, you can leverage the [`skip_duplicates`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#skip_duplicates) setting and ES will filter out duplicate suggestions from the response.